# "My another account" vs. "my other account"

Tags: grammar, adjectives, pronouns

A little debate going on here so I just want to know which one it is; I'm saying it's *my other account* since *my another* would be *my one other account*.

The other person insists they both can be used; however, I'm more than positive that it's only *other* in that context. Plus, *my another account* just sounds wrong to the ears.

Which one is it?

Answer (score 14):

It can't be "my another account" in my idiolect and in most standard dialects of English.

A standard analysis would be that the "an" element in "another" is an article, and that the use of a possessive adjective (like "my") replaces the article, so "my another ..." has effectively got the article duplicated, which you can't have.

Comment: This is further supported by the fact that we can say "that's another story" or — to be more emphatic — "that's a whole other story", but never "that's a whole another story".

Answer (score 7):

Possessive adjectives take the place of an article like *an* in a phrase (they're both determiners).  So mixing "my" with the "an" from *another* is incorrect.  Only *My other account* would be correct here.

Answer (score 0):

*My another account* is not correct; it is correct to say *my other account*.

Googling for *my another*, I found many instances of the phrase, but none of those are correct: sometimes who wrote it meant *another of my […]*; sometimes who wrote it simply meant *my other*.

> * That is my another problem. (That is another of my problems.)
>   I have been suspend from my another accounted!? (My other account has been suspended?)
>   * My another acc. is locked, I cannot login! (My other account is blocked. I cannot log in!)
>   * Could you please check my another essay. (Could you please check my other essay?)
>   * This is my another friend's profile. (This is another profile of my friend.)

Looking for *my another* on the *Corpus of Contemporary American*, and *Corpus of Historical American*, I found two instance of the phrase; in both the cases *my another* replaces *my mother*, and it is a transcription error, as *my another* is not used to mean *my mother*.

> **CARREY**: Yes, for me, my mother was in pain all the time. I wanted to fix her. She was depressed, so I wanted to make her laugh. But I remember when I was eight years old actually having the thought that I want to make my mother believe she gave birth to a miracle. That was the conscience thought I had, is that I want **my another** to feel like her life was worth something, that she did something special. And I was going to be that something special.
>   **KING**: A conscious thought at Eight?
>   **CARREY**: Conscious thought at eight years old.
>   **KING**: Did you help her?
>   **CARREY**: I did in certain ways and I couldn't in certain ways.
>   —Interview with Fran Drescher; Jim Carrey Discusses Movies, Comedy and Relationships.

> "I wasn't trying to hurt my father." He looked down. "I love my father."
>   "Then tell him so," said our mother.
>   Caleb looked at our father. "I'm telling you so," he said.
>   "Don't you love your mother, too?" she asked, smiling.
>   "Yes. I love **my another**."
>   "And your brother?"
>   He looked at me and his face changed. He smiled again, and he pulled me to him. "Yes. Oh, yes. I love my brother."
>   —Bloodline, Ernest J. Gaines.

Comment: @Rhodri: Is that also valid for Ernest J. Gaines?

Comment: @kiamlaluno: yes; I’m pretty sure both of these examples should read “my mother”.  In the second example, it’s celarly set up by the parallelism of the questions/answers: “I love my father.” […] “Don’t you love your mother too?” […] “I love my mother.” “And your brother?” […] “I love my brother.”

Comment: @PLL: I am sure that Ernest J. Gaines uses _my another_ to mean _my mother_, but I am not sure he wrote _my another_ by mistake, as he clearly wrote _mother_ in the previous sentence.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: well — I don’t have any evidence, but I would be really, really shocked if he is deliberately using “my another” to mean “my mother”.  I don’t mean to suggest he had the words confused; rather, that there is simply a typo in the text.  This is just the kind of error that even good publishers occasionally make — visually, the words are very similar, so it’s easily missed in proofreading — and I’ve never heard of ‘another’ being used to mean ‘mother’, in any dialect, and can’t find it mentioned in any dictionary…

Comment: If you right-click "amother" in Microsoft Word, it attempts to correct the spelling to "another".

Comment: @Zoot: I don't think _amother_ is related in someway to _my another_.

Comment: Agreed that both are likely typos.  Googling for the King interview, what you have there is a transcript from Larry King Live. It also has the following at the top: "THIS IS A RUSH TRANSCRIPT. THIS COPY MAY NOT BE IN ITS FINAL FORM AND MAY BE UPDATED."  Google couldn't find the second.

Comment: I changed how the answer was formulated; all I meant to say is that searching in CoCA and COHA I found two instances of _my another_.