# What's the difference between "another" and "other"?

Tags: word-choice, differences, determiners

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“My another account” vs. “my other account”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12618/my-another-account-vs-my-other-account)

Sometime it's vague for me when to use *other* vs *another*. For example,

> - You need to buy *other* book
> - You need to buy *another* book.

What's the difference between them, and when to use *other* or *another*?

Comment: "You need to buy other book" is ungrammatical.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["My another account" vs. "my other account"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12618/my-another-account-vs-my-other-account)?

Comment: "You need to buy the other book" would be correct, but it doesn't mean what "you need to buy another book" means.

Answer (score 4):

There's a formula:

> another = an + other.

Think of it as of an article plus the word "other" that have historically merged into one word.
Grammar requires some article before "other book"; either "the" or "a." Depending on the context, you get either "You need to buy the other book" (if, for instance, the guy bought only the first book out of the set of two) or "You need to buy an_other book" (any other).

Answer (score 2):

*Another* implies extra or additional with respect to the current amount.  "I'm going back for another sandwich."

*Other* is an adjective implying it is different than the object in discussion.  "Pass me my book.  Not that one, the other one."  It can also be a pronoun referring to things or people:  "Let's wait for the others to arrive."

Going back to your example, if I said "You need to buy the *other* book," I'd be implying a mistake has been made, *not* that you should buy an additional book as if I had said "You need to buy *another* book."

Answer (score 0):

English can use definite and indefinite articles before *other thing* (or *other* used as a noun) in the same way it uses them before nouns in general; by contrast, Spanish, for example, does not use an indefinite article before *otra cosa*.  But instead of writing *an other thing*, English writes *another thing*, losing a space.

So it is "You need to buy another book" in the same way it is "You need to buy a red book" developing from "You need to buy a book", but "You need to read my other book" coming from "You need to read my book".

You can break *another* apart as in "I'm not a partner or a bit-on-the-side, I'm a significant other".